# Rack cohomology as derived functor cohomology

Tags: gr.group-theory, cohomology, knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $X$ be a rack and $A$ be an $X$-module. By [this paper, p. 33](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202084), we can associate a cochain complex $C^\bullet(X,A)$ to the pair $(X,A)$. This complex is explicitly defined by a differential $d$. I wonder if the cohomology $H^\bullet(X,A)$ of the complex has an interpretation as derived functor cohomology. What functor from $X$-modules to $X$-modules do we have to derive? And how to show then the equivalence of the two definitions? I think the analogy to group cohomology is not very helpful, or can we somehow define the invariants of an $X$-module and make it fit?

Comment: If it is a derived functor, it's the derived functor of H^0. I'm not sure if this helps though :)

Comment: You are right, thank you.